# Haskell `hlint`, how can I add hint for wrong indentation, trailing spaces and etc?

Tags: haskell, static-analysis, hlint

I tried to use `hlint` package, but it gives no warnings or configuration for:

- trailing spaces
- last empty line
- spaces between arguments
- restrict tab indentation
- redundant lines

and other lint option stuff that relates to spaces/tabs and empty lines

I don't see how "Add new hint" can help me with this

Comment: Your title and question content are different; please clarify your question and what you've tried.

Comment: I couldn't find any good alternative to hlint, so I specified better by sticking to that library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://github.com/ndmitchell/hlint/issues/522:

> There is currently no support in HLint for issues which are about spacing or indentation. There are a few tools that deal with such concerns, search Haskell style checker for a few. I think HLint is probably better remaining free from whitespace concerns and letting other tools deal with them - I should probably link in the README to whatever the consensus is (I'm not sure)